# How to display integers in messagebox in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, string, user-interface, integer

I am trying to use a messagebox to debug a Visual C# program.  When I click a button I want a simple messagebox to popup and display the values of several integer variables.  This is what I have

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(myGame.P2.Money);
```

However the variable Money is an integer, and so I get this error:

Argument '1': cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

How do I get this to work?

Comment: What is the overall result you are trying to accomplish? If you are after methods of debugging, there a probably several that would work better for you than using a message box.

Comment: Note: Use the debugger.  It's awesome.  Get used to using it now, it will make your life easier in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(myGame.P2.Money.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(myGame.P2.Money.ToString());
```

?